# IOwinResponse is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, middleware

```
public class ErrorHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    async protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                var error = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>();
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                response.Content = new StringContent(ErrorTypeMessage.InternalServerError.ToString() + error["ExceptionMessage"] + " | " + error["StackTrace"], System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
                ; break;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

as above I use a handler to handle errors and use a custom middleware  to log errors as follows.

```
 public sealed class MyLogger : OwinMiddleware
{

    public MyLogger(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var record = new ApiEntry
        {
            CallerIdentity = identity
        };

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            record.Request = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();

            byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(record.Request);
            context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(requestData);
        });

        await Next.Invoke(context);

        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var stream = context.Response.Body;
            context.Response.Body = buffer;

            buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var bufferReader = new StreamReader(buffer))
            {
                record.Response = await bufferReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await buffer.CopyToAsync(stream);
                context.Response.Body = stream;
            }
        }

         //Record ApiEntry to a file as xml

    }
```

}

I m trying to read the error response which was set in the handler from the middleware. But `record.Response`is empty. Can I access httpResponseMessage inside middleware or is there a easy way to do that?

Comment: That is because you are trying to access the response on the way into the pipeline. not on the way out. you need to pass the context on through the pipeline and access it on its way back out. add `await Next.Invoke(context);` before trying to access the response.

Comment: no sorry I have added that(`await Next.Invoke(context);`) already before this code inside middleware. I can read the status code which is set by the **handler**  But not the message, I want to get the body inside IOwinResponse. I don't know whether I can read that inside IOwinResponse by setting it to `HttpResponseMessage`. I don't have a good idea. How `HttpResponseMessage` and `IOwinResponse` related.

Comment: `How HttpResponseMessage and IOwinResponse related.` They are not.

Comment: So what I m trying here is, I try to return a responseMessage with a custom message inside **Handler** and want to read that inside **Middleware** and log to a file inside middleware. I can read the status code inside middleware but not the responseMessage. Is it impossible. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Update original post to reflect the new information you are providing in comments

Comment: Updated. I can read request and response status correctly, but not IOwinResponse.body inside **Middleware** which is set inside **Handler**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132351/discussion-between-lasal-sethiya-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nikoshi as you said I also couldn't find a relationship between HttpResponseMessage and IOwinResponse. Finally i was able to resolve that using

> DelegatingHandler

implement a custom handler using a DelegatingHandler.